# How to set up a local web server to serve up a local html page

Tags: webserver, html

I want to work with local web pages using the seleniumIDE

It requires URL's.
So I'd like to set up localhost, 127.0.0.1
I don't need anyone else or network access to it, however it would be ideal if it could still load resources for css, js and their frameworks.

Basically I have a html page I want to see in a browser using a local server

What's the simplest way to get a local web server running so I can do this.  I'm on Ubuntu though I imagine the answer could apply to other *nix variations.

I'm more familiar with frameworks like ruby on rails which include a web server I can stop/start but in this case I don't need an application framework, just a basic web server for a html page via a get

Comment: What's wrong with just installing one, e.g. `apt-get install nginx`? For the actual setup read the manual and/or man pages.

Comment: does your website have any special requirements? e.g. `.htaccess` type config or URL rewriting? does it need a backend e.g. PHP and a database? if you just need static pages - do as marco suggested `apt-get install nginx` or `apt-get install apache2` - your `/etc/hosts` file already points localhost to `127.0.0.1` so you can just drop you files into document root, `/usr/share/nginx/html` for nginx or `/var/www/html` for apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adsf`—appropriately "A Dead Simple Fileserver"—seems like a great solution to this:

```
$ gem install adsf
Fetching: adsf-1.2.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed adsf-1.2.0
Parsing documentation for adsf-1.2.0
Installing ri documentation for adsf-1.2.0
Done installing documentation for adsf after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
$
$ adsf
[2015-12-06 08:24:03] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-12-06 08:24:03] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-12-06 08:24:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=811 port=3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the webserver you're planning to setup.

Could be as simple as: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, or `ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000` or as 'complex' as installing Apache and setting a value in httpd.conf - `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`.

Here's a big list of oneliners: https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255

Here's how to make Apache listen to localhost only: https://serverfault.com/questions/276963/make-apache-only-accessible-via-127-0-0-1-is-this-possible

You can check the outcome using something like `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`

For any other webserver, you're best bet is to look for something along the lines of 'Listen' or 'Interface' in the documentation.